# shell command not printing error to file when called inside php

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have the following shell command, when run in terminal it redirects both output and error (log) to separate files.

```
mummer -mum Reference.fasta Query.fasta > output.txt 2> err.txt
```

However the same command when called inside a php as below, it only prints output but not error (log).

```
shell_exec("mummer -mum '$ref_dest' '$sub_dest' > output.txt 2> err.txt");
```

Please let me know what has to done.

Update:

If no output and error (log) redirection done, it prints both of them on the screen.

Thanks,
Karthic K

Answer (score 0):

i think, the results of your command written to file and no console output.

try to remove the `> output.txt 2> err.txt`

```
shell_exec("mummer -mum '$ref_dest' '$sub_dest'");
```

Comment: No. It always prints on the console. I do the redirecting to a file.